# FIPA ACL implementation for Erlang

Tags: erlang, artificial-intelligence, agents-jade

Hio

i'm currently preparing some research in multi-agent systems using the concurrent language erlang and i would like to ask, if an implementation / framework for the FIPA ACL (Agent communication language) specification has been already published by someone in the world wide web similar like JADE for JAVA.

That would be great. Thanks for any hint.

FIPA: http://www.fipa.org/about/index.html
JADE: http://jade.tilab.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/gleber/exat - eXAT implements exactly the thing you want. eXAT is a FIPA ACL compatible implementation of multi-agent platform. I'm the active maintainer of the project and I'm using it for my research as well.

Comment: That looks very promising. I will check that.